# How to prevent access to a folder in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website which includes some data that must not be directly accessible by the client. I have that inside the folder as

```
root
|-Confidential
  |-Test.txt
  |- web.confid
  |- _PageStart.cshtml
web.config
```

..what I want to do is, to deny the access to the folder Confidential as a whole by the user, so that all of the content, is accessed directly would be redirected somewhere to shown a simple 404.

I have even tried using the web.config file as there was a solution in Stack Overflow, to create a new web.config file and then write this to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But it doesn't work for me. Then I tried using another method by replacing the name of the file, and writing it as **_Test.txt**. But I guess, ASP.NET only controls the .cshtml files and other ASP.NET files to be hidden this way.

Another method applied was, setting the error code to 404 by creating a new page called **_PageStart.cshtml** and then writing this code

```
@{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

..but again! The page was directly accessible. After all these methods, I came here, to find a solution to this problem. How can I deny the access to all of the file or the folder as a whole in ASP.NET.

[image]

Comment: This blog might be handy. [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a website which includes some data that must not be directly accessible by the client.

The simplest way to achieve this is to put the data in the App_Data folder.  That's what it's for.

Comment: This is the best way of doing it. No need of code, ASP.NET will handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

add this to your `<sysyem.webserver>` section

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="folderName"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: I have similar problem this segment no doubt prevent from accessing the file but how about allowing it to access through the web application.